# Quadratic formula does not work

Tags: quadratics

If I put the equation: $5x^2-x-4 =0$  in the quadratic formula, than I get

$x = 1$ or $x = \frac{-4}{5}$

but the real zeros are: $x = -1$ or $x = \frac{4}{5}$

Can somebody explain me if the quadratic formula fails or me?

Comment: You can verify that for example $-1$ is not a root, by plugging in.

Comment: You can verify that for example $.8$ is not a root, by plugging in.

Comment: Note that the quadratic formula works

Comment: I get x  = (1 + 9)/10  or (1-9)/10 ??

Comment: @MohammedelMahdadi You should. where did you get the "real zeros"?

Comment: Using graphic calculator and using option ''zero" or using option ''value'' than u will get (-1,0) or (4/5,0)

Comment: But when I use x= (-b +- sqrt b^2-4ac) /2a  i get the opposite ones

Comment: I don't know about your graphical calculator, but [this calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5x%5E2-x-4%3D0) says $x = 1$ or $-4/5$.

Comment: Ok I had made a mistake in the early beginning. Finnaly the equation should be 5x^2+x-4.

Comment: Mohammed I edited your question now it's the correct equation

Comment: @Oussama Boussif:  Please do not edit the question in such a way as to invalidate the whole purpose of asking the question.  The fact that the equation was incorrectly stated and the quadratic formula applied to the incorrect statement was the crucial premise of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it was meant to be $5x^2+x-4=0$. Then it would have those roots $-1$ and $\frac{4}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $5x^2 −x−4=0 $ you must use, $a=5, b=-1, c=-4$ in the formula$$\begin{align}x & =\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \\[2ex] & = \frac{-(-1)\pm\sqrt{(-1)^2-4(5)(-4)}}{2(5)} \\[2ex] & = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+80}}{10}\\[2ex] & = \frac{1\pm 9}{10}\\ \therefore x\in \{-\tfrac {4}{5}, 1\}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic formula comes from "completing the square". Let's do that to your examples:

\begin{eqnarray*}
5x^2-x-4 &=& 0 \\ \\
x^2 - \tfrac{1}{5}x - \tfrac{4}{5} &=& 0 \\ \\
x^2 - \tfrac{1}{5}x &=& \tfrac{4}{5} \\ \\
\left(x - \tfrac{1}{10}\right)^{2} - \tfrac{1}{100} &=& \tfrac{4}{5} \\ \\
\left(x - \tfrac{1}{10}\right)^{2} &=& \tfrac{4}{5} + \tfrac{1}{100} \\ \\
\left(x - \tfrac{1}{10}\right)^{2} &=& \tfrac{81}{100} \\ \\
x - \tfrac{1}{10} &=& \pm \tfrac{9}{10} \\ \\
x &=& \tfrac{1}{10} \pm \tfrac{9}{10} \\ \\
x&=& -\tfrac{4}{5} \ \ \text{or} \ \ 1
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

$5x^2-x-4$ does indeed have roots $x = 1, -\frac{4}{5}$, so you did it correctly.

To illustrate:

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
$$=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1^2-4*5*(-4)}}{2(5)}$$
$$=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{81}}{10}$$
$$= \frac{1\pm 9}{10}$$
$$x = 1, -\frac{4}{5}$$

As Peter said if you had meant $5x^2+x-4$ then your roots would have been $x = -1, +\frac{4}{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in the roots the quadratic formula gave you

$5(1)^2 - (1) - 4 $

$=5 - 5 $

$= 0$

And your other root

$5(- \frac{4}{5})^2 - (-\frac{4}{5}) - 4 $

$ = \frac{20}{5} -\frac{(16+4)}{5}$

$= 0$

And you can verify your roots work.

The quadratic formula is correct.

I recommend looking at the proof of the quadratic formula if you never have before to possibly help convince you that it does indeed work and more importantly *how* it works.

**if**

$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$

**then**

$ax^2 + bx = -c$

$a(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x) = -c$

$a(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + [\frac{b}{2a}]^2 - [\frac{b}{2a}]^2) = -c$

$a(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + [\frac{b}{2a}]^2) - a[\frac{b}{2a}]^2$ = -c

$a(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + [\frac{b}{2a}]^2) = \frac{b}{4a}^2 -c$

$a(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 = \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}$

$(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 = \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$

$(x + \frac{b}{2a}) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}} = \frac{\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

$x=-\frac{b}{2a} \pm \frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$

The quadratic formula is devised by observing and analyzing the relationship between the objects $a$,$b$, and $c$ in the form of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$.